# Mysql 1:n JOIN SELECT query

Tags: mysql

I have a web application where users can make posts and other users can make comments. I am using a mysql database to hold my data. Currently I have two tables. One has all posts and one has all comments. I have the foreign key `postID` on my comments table. My question now is how I can get the data from the database back to my app. I have tried the following query but it does not work. I will explain why in a minute. Here is the query I tried:  `SELECT posts.title, posts.body, comments.userID, comments.comment FROM posts INNER JOIN comments ON posts.postID = comments.postID WHERE posts.postID = comingfromwebapp`. The problem is IF there are zero comments nothing comes in. And If there are multiple comments and the post is too big, the result from the query is too big because in every row I receive the same posts.body for every comment. What is the correct way to implement this? I am rather new to SQL databases and have only used NOSQL before.

Comment: the best way is getting data in two different queries. 1st is to retrieve post and 2nd query to fetch its comments

Comment: So joins are for different purposes right? Two queries will not have an impact on performance?

Comment: Do not use `inner join` in your case. You must use `left outer join` or `right outer join`

Comment: it depends on the scenario. here post can be big and it is bad idea to fetch it every time along with its comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what we have the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for.

This would return at least the post even if no comments are yet in the system (beware: Your comments.* values would then return as NULL - you'll have to be prepared for that)

```
SELECT posts.title, posts.body, comments.userID, comments.comment 
   FROM posts 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON posts.postID = comments.postID 
WHERE posts.postID = comingfromwebapp
```

**BUT**

This would fetch the full post title and body for each and every comment given to one post. Which is overkill.

You might want to consider making one SQL for fetching post data and one (which might return 0 rows) for fetching all comments for that post ID:

```
SELECT posts.title, posts.body
   FROM posts WHERE postid = commingfromwebapp
```

(display your post)

```
SELECT comments.userID, comments.comment 
   FROM  comments WHERE comments.postID = comingfromwebapp
```

(display all comments if there are any)

Comment: So I will have to make a benchmark based on the size of this posts to see which option performs better? That seems ok to me. Thank you very much for the info.

Comment: see my edit for two-sql-approach. You probably want to to two-query approach in any case at it improves code readability a lot (two separate queries and loops over results and so on) - the if NULL stuff would be confusing else

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use two different queries.
1- to fetch posts,
2- to fetch their comments.

while displaying on your app you can combine them